# HtmlGenericControl gives me an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: c#, asp.net, htmlgenericcontrol

I am trying to change the css of the content page which inherits its css from the master page.
I tried the below but for some reason I am getting the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

Below is my cs code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    HtmlGenericControl mycontrol = (HtmlGenericControl)this.Page.Master.FindControl("ul1").FindControl("li1") as HtmlGenericControl;

      mycontrol.Attributes.Add("class", "newCSS");    
 }
```

Find the masterpage content here:

```
    <div id="menu">
        <ul id="ul1" runat="server">
            <li id="li1" runat="server">
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl ="home.aspx">Home</asp:HyperLink></li>
            <li id="li2" runat="server">
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl ="AboutUs.aspx">About Us</asp:HyperLink></li>
            <li id="li3" runat="server">
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/courses.aspx" >Courses</asp:HyperLink></li>
            <li id="li4" runat="server">
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/News.aspx" >News</asp:HyperLink></li>
            <li id="li5" runat="server">
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink5" runat="server" NavigateUrl="ContactInfo.aspx" >Contact Us</asp:HyperLink></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The css as below:

```
 #menu a:hover
{
    background-color: white;
    color: #bee2f1;
}

 .newCSS
{
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;

}
```

I tried giving the .FindControl ID as the HyperLink ID instead of the ul, li Id as shown above but that did not work either.

Edit:
Tried the following in the cs page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        HtmlGenericControl mycontrol = (HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("ul1").FindControl("li1"); 
        mycontrol.Attributes.Add("class", "newCSS");    
}
```

No compiler error but the code does not function.

Comment: Have you tried doing the following 
WebControl mycontrol = (WebControl)Page.FindControl("ul1");

Comment: @DJ KRAZE Yes I tried it. I get the same error.

Comment: have you tried moving the runat="server" up as Thousand has suggested

Comment: @DJ Yes I did that. Let me just edit it in the question. It was a simple mistake I made while playing around for a solution before posting the question.

Comment: HtmlGenericControl myControl = (HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("ul1"); should do the trick

Comment: Almost all cases of NullReferenceException are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: @DJ Ok no errors this time but the css of the menu did not change. The code did not function.

Comment: update your code with the now working solution at the top of your original question

Comment: @DJ KRAZE I have updated the question after the changes.

Comment: how come you have this runat="server" on ui1 and not the rest.. be consistent

Comment: @John Wonderful post and I now know that the problem is with finding the ul and li ID values. I tried troubleshooting by adding the "if" clause as well for a possible null value but that did not yield either. Any help regarding to this question is most appreciated.

Comment: @DJ KRAZE Since I was only concentrating on the home page, I did not bother changing the other ones. But now that I have done, there was no change in the outcome :(

Comment: No need to nest your `FindControl()` calls. Simply look for the `<li>` item: `HtmlGenericControl mycontrol = (HtmlGenericControl)this.Page.Master.FindControl("li1") as HtmlGenericControl;`

Comment: @andleer I tried that before posting the question here, andleer. I do not get an error but the code does not work. I am puzzled and clueless.

Answer (score 0):

There is a recursive function I use for situations like this.  When you need to find/edit content on the master page from a content page, it's always tricky.  This function helped me out a lot.  In the example, I am using it to find the return button of my Menu on my master page called `Menu2` by passing it the ID of the button.

****Method***

```
public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)
    {
        if (id == string.Empty)
            return null;

        if (root.ID == id)
            return root;

        foreach (Control c in root.Controls)
        {
            Control t = FindControlRecursive(c, id);
            if (t != null)
            {
                return t;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

****Usage***

```
Menu menu2 = (Menu)FindControlRecursive(Master.Page, "ReturnButton");
```

Using this method, I can now access the Menu of my master page from the content page.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Ok I understood the concept. Thank you. I need to learn more about this as I am very new to c#. I will study, solve this question and post the entire answer here.